# Bootstrap nav menu not collapsing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I can not see why my nav menu does not collapse on smaller resolutions. It is responsive, but I do not get the neat dropdown, all nav menu items are just displayed.

How do I get it to collapse?
Here is my Navbar code

```
<!-- Nav Bar -->
      <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <a href="index.html" class="pull-left visible-md visible-lg "><img src="http://pcduck.com/pirates/images/logo.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="BlackHeart Pirates Guild Vault"/></a>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="http://pcduck.com/pirates/index.php" >Home</a></li>
        <li ><a href="http://www.blackheartpirates.com/forums/" >Forums</a></li>
        <li ><a href="#">Raids</a></li>
        <li ><a href="#">Apply</a></li>
        <li ><a href="http://pcduck.com/pirates/index.php/about">About</a></li>
        <li ><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
      </nav>
      <!--End Nav Bar -->
```

http://pcduck.com/pirates/index.php

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing some important code which displays the "hamburger menu" on smaller screens and collapses your nav links.  Here is what your navbar code should look like to achieve what you want:

```
<!-- Nav Bar -->
      <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
         <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
           <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="http://pcduck.com/pirates/index.php" >Home</a></li>
        <li ><a href="http://www.blackheartpirates.com/forums/" >Forums</a></li>
        <li ><a href="#">Raids</a></li>
        <li ><a href="#">Apply</a></li>
        <li ><a href="http://pcduck.com/pirates/index.php/about">About</a></li>
        <li ><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
          </div>
      </nav>
      <!--End Nav Bar -->
```

I have left out your logo image because it will be up to you to decide where it is place on the screen.